# Google Maps API V3 map container element duplicated in IE9

Tags: asp.net, google-maps-api-3, internet-explorer-9

This may be a duplicate of a question somewhere, but I am unable to come up with the keywords to produce it.

I am using the Google Maps API V3 and following the simple tutorial provided at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial. Everything is fine except in IE9, which is rendering in IE9 Standards mode. The problem is that when the map is loaded on an incredibly bare-bones ASP.NET forms page, the resulting HTML has the `div` container for the map, *twice*! This is causing layout issues because as described in the tutorial:

> Note that the map will always take its size from that of its containing element, so you must always set a size on that  explicitly.

So, the `div` containing my map must be either set to some amount of pixels or 100%, the same value as its DOM parent. This is fine in FireFox and Chrome, where the HTML source ends up roughly:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 ...
</head>
<body class="no-layout"><form name="aspnetForm" method="post" action="TestPopup.aspx" id="aspnetForm">
<div>
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDw... />
</div>
<div class="map" />
</form></body>
</html>
```

But in IE9, we end up with:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 ...
</head>
<body class="no-layout"><form name="aspnetForm" method="post" action="TestPopup.aspx" id="aspnetForm">
<div>
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDw..." />
</div>
<div class="map" />
</form>
<div class="map" />
</body>
</html>
```

This page is a (working) simplification of the problem but this is an actual issue in pages because the map class has width and height set. The second `div` with this class has the same style, pushing content down.

Comment: silly question but, you are defining using an `id` and not a `class` right? Also you are defining the container, and not using any js or jquery to append the container to the body DOM.

Comment: @Mike, I am using a class because I'm using jQuery to get the container and passing the first element to initialize the map. By using an ID, IE9 created invalid markup since there will be two `div`s in the document with the same ID. jQuery is not being used to append anything anywhere.